# Convert Thread to Thread-Pool On Messaging Queue Consumer

Tags: python, threadpool

I have a python code like below:

```
import logging
import time
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

from aio_pika import connect, Message, DeliveryMode
import json

from aio_pika.abc import AbstractIncomingMessage

class RevenueQueue(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connection = None
        self.channel = None
        self.result_queue = None
        self.problem_queue = None
        self.queue = None

    async def init(self, loop):
        """ Init """
        self.connection = await connect(cloudamqp_url, loop=loop)
        self.channel = await self.connection.channel()
        await self.channel.set_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        self.queue = await self.channel.declare_queue(request_queue,
                                                      durable=True)
        await self.queue.consume(self.callback)
        self.result_queue = await self.channel.declare_queue(result_queue, durable=True)
        self.problem_queue = await self.channel.declare_queue(result_problem_queue, durable=True)

    async def callback(self, message: AbstractIncomingMessage):
        """ Callback """
        request = json.loads(message.body.decode("utf-8"))
        try:
            tic = time.perf_counter()
            result = ...
            result_message = Message(
                bytes(json.dumps(result, default=str), encoding='utf8'),
                delivery_mode=DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT)
            await self.channel.default_exchange.publish(
                result_message, routing_key=revenue_result_queue)
        except Exception as e:
            error_message = Message(
                bytes(json.dumps(request, default=str), encoding='utf8'),
                delivery_mode=DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT)
            await self.channel.default_exchange.publish(
                error_message, routing_key=result_problem_queue)
        finally:
            await message.ack()


async def listen_queue(loop):
 for _ in range(5):
    td = RevenueQueue()
    td.init()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        asyncio.ensure_future(listen_queue(loop))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
```

I want to convert this thread logic to ThreadPoolExecutor. How can I handle it? Is there any suggestion?

I want to use ThreadPoolExecutor because I don't want to struggle with zombie threads. I believe that ThreadPoolExecutor can handle it.

Code looks complex but it is easy indeed. It is a request listener. It listens requests and handles them then if the result exists send the result to result_queue otherwise sen d it to problem_queue.

Comment: The `RevenueQueue` objects do nothing when `start`ed as threads (no `target`, no `run` method).

Comment: it is a queue listener. It calls consume method with init method

Comment: According to the update, no additional threads are used. Everything runs in the main thread.

Comment: @MichaelButscher How can I spread it to multiple thread?

Comment: Override the `run` method and in it run an async event loop which executes the `init` method.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I don't understand it. Could you please show it as code implementation?

Comment: Create a `run` method in `RevenueQueue` which calls `asyncio.run(self.init())`. The `init` method shouldn't retrieve the loop by parameter but by `loop = asyncio.get_running _loop()` and in `listen_queue` replace `td.init()` (which doesn't do anything, by the way, because it must be awaited) by `td.start()`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher sorry but it is not clear. Could you please write it as an answer?